# jest not covering functions declared as const

Tags: reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, react-redux, jestjs

I am using jest for improving my code coverage.
below is my configuration:

index.tsx

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDom from "react-dom";
import './index.css';
import App from './app';
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { setupStore } from "./store";

const store = setupStore();

const Portal = () => {
    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <App />        
        </Provider>
    );
};

ReactDom.render(<Portal />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

and index.test.tsx:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { setupStore } from "../store";
jest.mock("react-dom", () => ({ render: jest.fn() }));
jest.mock('../app');

const store = setupStore();

describe('Test index.js', () => {
    it("Should render app without crashing", () => {
        const div = document.createElement("div");
        div.id = "root";
        document.body.appendChild(div);
        require('../index');
        // expect(ReactDOM.render).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
        //     <Portal />,
        //     document.getElementById("root")
        // );
    });
});
```

So far, the test runs successfully. but statement coverage is only 75%.
when i investigated further, I found out that below function is not covered.

```
const Portal = () => {
    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <App />        
        </Provider>
    );
};
```

I m not sure what I am doing wrong. kindly suggest.

Comment: I think you have to mock the Provider here to get the full coverage.

Comment: @SarunUK did not work

Comment: _Don't_ unit test the index file. You should have higher-level tests that tell you pretty quickly if the whole app is failing to start entirely.